# Leaflet: Find my "this" in GeoJSON.pointToLayer function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In leaflet, I have a class that extends `L.GeoJSON`:

```
L.MyLayer = L.GeoJSON.extend
({
    initialize: function ()
    {
        this.markers = [];
...
```

I redefined the `pointToLayer` method to create markers for points:

```
pointToLayer : function(feature, latlng)
{
   var marker = L.marker(lat...
   ...
   return marker;
},
```

I need to store all the markers locally, so I created the `markers` array.
My problem is that if I call `this.` inside `pointToLayer` function I obtain the `Window` object instead obtaining the current instance of `MyLayer`.

How can I get a reference to current `MyLayer` instance inside `pointToLayer` function?

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass the pointToLayer function as an option on layer instantiation.

```
var layer = L.myLayer(geojson, {
    pointToLayer: function (ftr, latLng) {
        return L.marker([latlng.lat, latlng.lng]);
    }
});
```

And then get markers off the layer instance.

```
var markers = layer.getLayers();
```